# Why does "\n" appear in my string output?

Tags: python, html, dataframe, web-scraping

I have elements that I've scraped off of a website and when I print them using the following code, they show up neatly as spaced out elements.

```
print("\n" + time_element)
```

prints like this

F
4pm-5:50pm

but when I pass time_element into a dataframe as a column and convert it to a string, the output looks like this

```
 #   b'        \n                F\n        \n                4pm-5:50pm\n
```

I am having trouble understanding why it appears so and how to get rid of this "\n" character. I tried using regex to match the "F" and the "4pm-5:50pm" and I thought this way I could separate out the data I need. But using various methods including

```
# Define the list and the regex pattern to match
time = df['Time']
pattern = '[A-Z]+'
# Filter out all elements that match the pattern
filtered = [x for x in time if re.match(pattern, x)]
print(filtered)
```

I get back an empty list.

From my research, I understand the "\n" represents a new line and that there might be invisible characters. However, I'm not understanding more about how they behave so I can get rid of them/around them to extract the data that I need.

When I pass the data to csv format, it prints like this all in one cell

F
4pm-5:50pm

but I still end up in the similar place when it comes to separating out the data that I need.

Comment: `match` won't work you need `re.search` because your pattern is not at start.

Comment: in the dataframe you just get the representation of the data, hence the `\n`. Try printing the data.

Comment: re.search helped to answer the question about why my lists were coming back empty

Comment: you can filter out all blanks too: `"".join(x for x in time if not x.isspace())`

Answer (score 1):

you can use the function `strip()` when you extract data from the website to avoid "\n"

Comment: that should probably work for the OP, yes. There is no function `strip()`. `strip()` is a method applied to the string (or bytes object) you want to strip

Comment: strip() helped but there are still some "\n" left. i need to work through the web scraper more to extract just what i need.